# CTest gives “not run” and “BAD_COMMAND” although commands work directly

Tags: cmake, ctest

I have some code that I would like to test with a small script. It is not completely finished, but it should at least fail later on. This is the script:

```
set -e
set -u
set -x

echo "Hello!"
"$1/contract" -i test_all.ini
h5diff FILE1 FILE2
```

When I call it from the command line using

```
/usr/bin/bash \
    "/home/mu/Projekte/sLapH-contractions/integration-test-L4/run-integration-test" \
    "/home/mu/Build/sLapH-contractions"
```

it works as expected:

```
$ /usr/bin/bash "/home/mu/Projekte/sLapH-contractions/integration-test-L4/run-integration-test" "/home/mu/Build/sLapH-contractions"
+ echo 'Hello!'
Hello!
+ /home/mu/Build/sLapH-contractions/contract -i test_all.ini
CANNOT open input file: test_all.ini
+ h5diff FILE1 FILE2
h5diff: <FILE1>: unable to open file
```

Now I would like to run this test from `ctest` or `make test` in my project. I have added the following to my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
enable_testing()

add_test(NAME sanity-1
    COMMAND bash -c "echo Sanity 1"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY /tmp)

add_test(NAME integration-L4
    COMMAND bash "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/integration-test-L4/run-integration-test" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/integration-test-L4/integration-test-L4")
```

When I run it with `ctest`, it does not even run the test!

```
$ ctest -VV
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :/home/mu/Build/sLapH-contractions/DartConfiguration.tcl
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :/home/mu/Build/sLapH-contractions/DartConfiguration.tcl
Test project /home/mu/Build/sLapH-contractions
Constructing a list of tests
Done constructing a list of tests
Updating test list for fixtures
Added 0 tests to meet fixture requirements
Checking test dependency graph...
Checking test dependency graph end
test 1
    Start 1: sanity-1

1: Test command: /usr/bin/bash "-c" "echo Sanity 1"
1: Test timeout computed to be: 9.99988e+06
1: Sanity 1
1/2 Test #1: sanity-1 .........................   Passed    0.00 sec
test 2
    Start 2: integration-L4

2: Test command: /usr/bin/bash "/home/mu/Projekte/sLapH-contractions/integration-test-L4/run-integration-test" "/home/mu/Build/sLapH-contractions"
2: Test timeout computed to be: 9.99988e+06
2/2 Test #2: integration-L4 ...................***Not Run   0.00 sec

50% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 2

Total Test time (real) =   0.01 sec

The following tests FAILED:
          2 - integration-L4 (BAD_COMMAND)
Errors while running CTest
```

I have not found anything helpful on the `BAD_COMMAND` error.

What could be going on that prevents this test from being run at all?

Comment: Does anything change if you remove the sanity test and have just one test, the erroring one?

Comment: Not really, the real test then fails in the same way.

Comment: Does the directory `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/integration-test-L4/integration-test-L4` exist?

Comment: @Angew: No, it does not. But I use absolute paths there, so I don't see how that particular path could be build up ...

Comment: That's the working directory you're specifying. You should make sure it exists.

Comment: @Angew: Awesome catch! Yes, that was the problem! Do you want to turn this into an answer? If not, I will write something up such that people from web searches can see the connection of `BAD_COMMAND` and nonexistant working directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're specifying `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/integration-test-L4/integration-test-L4"` as the working directory. Make sure that the directory actually exists (or remove the last bit if the repetition is in error).

Answer (score 2):

I saw similar issues on Windows with an older CMake (v2.8.12) - a command that runs at the prompt but fails with `BAD_COMMAND` from CTest. The underlying issue was due to the executable search performed by the shell - see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1330358/why-does-a-file-get-opened-when-i-write-its-name-without-extensions-in-the-com) for more info.

So adding a test with `add_test(my_test c:/node_js/npm run test)` doesn't work because, although `c:\node_js\npm` exists, it actually executes `c:\node_js\npm.cmd`. Fixed by appending `.cmd` to the command to be executed.